# How to get the underlaying viewmodel of a view/region from another view in WPF Prism

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have 3 regions namely Menu,Toolbar and Content. When a module(ie customer) is clicked in Menu view it will navigate to the respective view in content region, after editing the values in the textboxes I need to save that to DB. How to get the underlaying view model of the active view and send to DAL when save button is clicked in Toolbar view?.
Shell.xaml:

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="65" Margin="1">
        <Border CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="1" >
                <ContentControl Name="menuControl" PrismRegions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infra:RegionNames.MenuRegion}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="1">
        <Border CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
                <ContentControl Name="toolbarControl" PrismRegions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infra:RegionNames.ToolbarRegion}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="2">
        <Border CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <StackPanel Margin="5" >
            <ContentControl Name="contentControl"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" PrismRegions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infra:RegionNames.ContentRegion}"/>
    </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Menu.xaml:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Name="btnHome" Background="Transparent" Margin="1" ToolTip="Home" Command="{x:Static inf:ApplicationCommands.NavigationCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Type mod:HomeView}">
        <TextBlock Height="32" Width="32" Text ="">
            <TextBlock.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Modules;component/Icons/home_32.png"/>
            </TextBlock.Background>
        </TextBlock>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="btnBank" Background="Transparent" Margin="1" ToolTip="Bank" Command="{x:Static inf:ApplicationCommands.NavigationCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Type mod:BankView}">
        <TextBlock Height="32" Width="32" Text ="">
            <TextBlock.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Modules;component/Icons/bank_64.png"/>
            </TextBlock.Background>
        </TextBlock>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Name="btnCustomer" Background="Transparent" Margin="1" ToolTip="Customer" Command="{x:Static inf:ApplicationCommands.NavigationCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Type mod:CustomerView}">
    <TextBlock Height="32" Width="32" Text ="">
        <TextBlock.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Modules;component/Icons/customer_128.ico"/>
        </TextBlock.Background>
    </TextBlock>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Name="btnEmployee" Background="Transparent" Margin="1" ToolTip="Employee" Command="{x:Static inf:ApplicationCommands.NavigationCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Type mod:EmployeeView}">
    <TextBlock Height="32" Width="32" Text ="">
        <TextBlock.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Modules;component/Icons/employee_128.png"/>
        </TextBlock.Background>
    </TextBlock>
    </Button>
```

Toolbar.xaml:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="1" Name="btnAdd" Height="35" Width="35"  ToolTip="Add" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" CommandParameter="Add" >
            <TextBlock Height="30" Width="30" Text ="">
                <TextBlock.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Modules;component/Icons/plus_32.png"/>
                </TextBlock.Background>
            </TextBlock>
        </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" Name="btnEdit" Height="35" Width="35" ToolTip="Edit" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding EditCommand}" CommandParameter="Edit"  >
            <TextBlock Height="30" Width="30" Text ="">
                <TextBlock.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Modules;component/Icons/pencil_32.png"/>
                </TextBlock.Background>
            </TextBlock>
        </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="1" Name="btnSave" Height="35" Width="35" ToolTip="Save" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" CommandParameter="Save" >
            <TextBlock Height="30" Width="30" Text ="">
                <TextBlock.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Modules;component/Icons/save_32.png"/>
                </TextBlock.Background>
            </TextBlock>
        </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Margin="1" Name="btnPrint" Height="35" Width="35" ToolTip="Print" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" CommandParameter="Print" >
            <TextBlock Height="30" Width="30" Text ="">
                <TextBlock.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Modules;component/Icons/print_32.png"/>
                </TextBlock.Background>
            </TextBlock>
        </Button>
```

UI Design:

[image: Attached the Image]

Comment: can you post your content region view code and viewmodel code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your view's state is entirely present in the viewmodel. In your scenario of Button being out side the viewmodel of the form to save what you can do is:

In tool bar viewmodel: 
Raise an event that Save button is clicked

```
myEventAggregator.RaiseEvent<SaveButtonClicked>().Publish(args);
```

On viewmodel constructor:
subscribe for the event that you raise when you click on save button in toolbar region

```
myEventAggregator.GetEvent<SaveButtonClicked>().Subscribe(yourSubscriberDelegate);
```

On Exit of the form or cancel of form: 
Unsubscribe for the event. (this makes sure you don't have multiple active forms saving the data at the same time)

```
myEventAggregator.GetEvent<SaveButtonClicked>().UnSubscribe(yourSubscriberDelegate);
```

For this you need Event aggregator knowledge of publish and subscribe. Find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx)